# bitwise AND in arithmetic operation

Tags: binary, decimal

Bitwise OR(|) is similar to arithmetic addition(+) i.e. A|B = A+B (if A!=B)

Like, 2|4 = 6 and 2+4 = 6

That means there is a way to get "OR" result in by doing addition in arithmetic context.

Is there a similar way to get bitwise "AND" result by doing arithmetic operation.

i.e. A&B = aithmetic_op(A,B)

A = 2^k (k=1,2,3,4...)

B = 2^k (k=1,2,3,4...)

Thanks

Comment: What about 3+2 and 3|2 that should be 5..............?????

Comment: Sorry for not including the condition A = 2^k (k=1,2,3,4.....) same for B

Answer (score 1):

Just as `OR` is analogous to `+`, `AND` is analogous to `*`

```
0 AND 0 = 0 * 0 = 0

0 AND 1 = 0 * 1 = 0

1 AND 0 = 1 * 0 = 0

1 AND 1 = 1 * 1 = 1
```

Note that this only works for a single bit (as does the analogy between `OR` and `+` that you mention), due to the effects of arithmetic carries.